Fastboot mode recognizes my device but adb doesn't
ADB cannot recognize my device in recovery mode. USB debugging is disabled and I think that's the reason why. Also, how can I enable USB debugging via fastboot (if that's even possible)?

​not ​possible​

Not possible. If you want to enable USB tethering from the device, you have to do it from Developer options in Settings. Or you can use an ADB command:
adb shell svc usb setFunctions rndis

But this still requires the device to be booted into Android.
